# Stuck on GStreamer logging

Tags: c, debugging, logging, gstreamer

I am trying to have my GStreamer application log information piped through `GST_DEBUG` and `GST_ERROR` to a log file. I have tried setting environment variables `GST_DEBUG` and `GST_DEBUG_FILE` both in `CMakeLists.txt` and in code, but have no luck.

Q-1: What do I need to do to fix logging?

Q-2: Can I have logging via `GST_DEBUG`, `GST_ERROR`, etc. and `stdout` at the same time?

When `GST_DEBUG("THIS IS A TEST".")` is executed, there is no output in the terminal nor the log file.

In `CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0)

set(GST_DEBUG "*:6")
set(GST_DEBUG_FILE /var/log/myapp.log)
set(GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR ${ROOT_DIR}/tmp)

add_executable(myapp, ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_compile_options(myapp, ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${BUILD_FLAGS} ${GST_CFLAGS} ${GST_DEBUG_OPTIONS} -g -ggdb -Wall -pedantic -enable-gst-debug=yes)
```

Note that for some reason I cannot build when prefixing enable-gst-debug=yes with two "-", i.e., "--enable-gst-debug=yes" does not compile, but "-enable-gst-debug=yes" does.

Additionally, the GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR doesn't work from CMakeLists.txt, but if I run my application from a script with "GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR='../tmp' 'myapp'" then the dot files are generated. Figured this might be related.

In C:

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC(myapp)
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT myapp

// Called previously when main parses args
g_option_context_add_group(pCntx, gst_init_get_option_group());

void init_myapp() {

    gst_init(NULL, NULL);// I know this is rather redundant because gst_init_get_option_group() has been called already.
    GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT(myapp, "myapp", 0, "Custom debugging cat.");
    setenv("GST_DEBUG", "*:6", 1);
    setenv("GST_DEBUG_FILE", "/var/log/myapp.log", 1);

    GST_DEBUG("THIS IS A TEST.");
}
```

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/stable/gst-running.html), GStreamer must be compiled with `--enable-gst-debug=yes`. So, does your GStreamer have gst-debug enabled?

Comment: perhaps this might help you: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put that in the question? The comment section is very limiting for large code snippets, it's not readable. Thanks. Btw after editing your question, please remove the comment.

Comment: `--enable-gst-debug=yes` is an command line option of `configure` for when you are building the GStreamer library, it's not a GCC option. My point was that your GStreamer version might not be compiled with this option.

Comment: As far as I can see the `GST_DEBUG*` are environment variables you have to set when you execute your program. They are meaningless when compiling, you can remove their definitions from the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: Hi Pablo, thank you for your help. Taking your advise, I found out that I can pass these settings when calling on my executable; e.g., GST_DEBUG_FILE="../tmp/myapp.log" myapp. Ideally, I would like to do this from code or from the cmake build system, but for now I guess it will have to do. Thank you!

Comment: For some reason, the setenv functions just aren't working for me :( I can hit these while executing my app, in gdb, but no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Cmake is the building system, it has nothing to with environment variables for the running process.
What you can do is set your default values with cmake like this:

```cmake
# for escaped definitions
cmake_policy(SET CMP0005 NEW)

set(DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG "*:6" CACHE STRING "Default value for GST_DEBUG")
set(DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_FILE /var/log/myapp.log CACHE STRING "Default value for GST_DEBUG_FILE")
set(DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR ${ROOT_DIR}/tmp CACHE STRING "Default value for GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR")

add_definitions("-DDEFAULT_GST_DEBUG=\"${DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG}\"")
add_definitions("-D=DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_FILE\"${DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_FILE}\"")
add_definitions("-DDEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=\"${DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR}\"")

...
```

The correct way of setting the environment variable is by using

```bash
$ export VAR=VAL
```

or

```bash
$ VAR=VAL ./a.out
```

The user must be able to override your default values, don't take that ability
from the user.

`setenv` should also work, but even though [the documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html) never mentions
it, I suspect that these environment variables have to bet set **before**
`gst_init(NULL, NULL);` is called, because I think this is the place where the
environment variables are evaluated, so changing them afterwards would probably
have no effect on the behaviour of the logging in GStreamer.

You have also the option to pass `argc` and `argv` to `gst_init`, but the
documentation says that *unknown command line options cause this function
to abort program execution* <sup>[cite](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-Gst.html#gst-init)</sup>, and the [API documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-Gst.html)
shows how to deal with it.

So you could do it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC(myapp)
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT myapp

int init_myapp();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // the setenvs must come before the gst_init
    char *env = getenv("GST_DEBUG");
    if(env == NULL)
        setenv("GST_DEBUG", DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG, 1);

    env = getenv("GST_DEBUG_FILE");
    if(env == NULL)
        setenv("GST_DEBUG_FILE", DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_FILE, 1);

    env = getenv("GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR");
    if(env == NULL)
        setenv("GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR", DEFAULT_GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR, 1);

    // if you must
    g_option_context_add_group(pCntx, gst_init_get_option_group());

    init_myapp();
    ...
}

int init_myapp()
{


    // this should be the first call!
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);

    GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT(myapp, "myapp", 0, "Custom debugging cat.");
}
```

Now you can change the default values in cmake with `cmake
-DDEFAULT_GST_DEBUG=value` or with `ccmake`.

Hope that helps you.